# trying to optimize listview and failed

Tags: android, optimization, listview, io

I am trying to adopt Romain Guy's recommendation from google IO last year of a ViewHolder for a list to optimize list view for the example from:
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
(thanks to admin)
but whenever I try to flip through the list or even make it move a little bit, the application crashes, what is going on? any help would be appreciated :) 
here is what I did >

```
private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {
    private ArrayList<Order> items;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            holder.bt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Order o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            if (holder.tt != null) {
                holder.tt.setText("Name: " + o.getOrderName());
            }
            if (holder.bt != null) {
                holder.bt.setText("Status: " + o.getOrderStatus());
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I got, sorry I don't know how to format it >

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.softberries.lve.SoftwarePassionView$OrderAdapter.getView(SoftwarePassionView.java:98)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2065)
    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3315)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: At the time of crash what the message is appeared in logcat

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`. But I do not see where you invoke `setTag()` for `convertView` in body of `if (convertView == null) {...}` .

So, I guess you forgot the line:

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception. Use **getCount()** method of array adapter to declare the size of the list.

Comment: add the getCount, still the same problem